# JSONArray without array name (earthquake example)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Regarding another thread here i try too, to get a json array form a json. I have the following files :

earthquake.json

```
[{
        "eqid": "merge",
        "magnitude": 8.8,
        "lng": 142.369,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2011-03-11 04:46:23",
        "depth": 24.4,
        "lat": 38.322
    }, {
        "eqid": "merge2",
        "magnitude": 8.6,
        "lng": 93.0632,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2012-04-11 06:38:37",
        "depth": 22.9,
        "lat": 2.311
    }, {
        "eqid": "2007hear",
        "magnitude": 8.4,
        "lng": 101.3815,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2007-09-12 09:10:26",
        "depth": 30,
        "lat": -4.5172
    }, {
        "eqid": "c00090da",
        "magnitude": 8.2,
        "lng": 92.4522,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2012-04-11 08:43:09",
        "depth": 16.4,
        "lat": 0.7731
    }, {
        "eqid": "2007aqbk",
        "magnitude": 8,
        "lng": 156.9567,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2007-04-01 18:39:56",
        "depth": 10,
        "lat": -8.4528
    }, {
        "eqid": "2007hec6",
        "magnitude": 7.8,
        "lng": 100.9638,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2007-09-12 21:49:01",
        "depth": 10,
        "lat": -2.5265
    }, {
        "eqid": "b000g7x7",
        "magnitude": 7.8,
        "lng": 62.0532,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2013-04-16 08:44:20",
        "depth": 82,
        "lat": 28.1069
    }, {
        "eqid": "a00043nx",
        "magnitude": 7.7,
        "lng": 100.1139,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2010-10-25 12:42:22",
        "depth": 20.6,
        "lat": -3.4841
    }, {
        "eqid": "2010utc5",
        "magnitude": 7.7,
        "lng": 97.1315,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2010-04-06 20:15:02",
        "depth": 31,
        "lat": 2.3602
    }, {
        "eqid": "2009mebz",
        "magnitude": 7.6,
        "lng": 99.9606,
        "src": "us",
        "datetime": "2009-09-30 08:16:09",
        "depth": 80,
        "lat": -0.7889
    }]
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package ayub.khosa.json_parsing;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity 
{
String tag = "AYUB";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    Log.d(tag, "setContentView  ");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONArray json = null;
    try {
        json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.0.104/earthquakes.json");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(tag, "json object  "); 
    try{
        Collection<?> result = null;
        JSONArray json1 = new JSONArray(result);
 //         // ...

        for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){                        
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = json1.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
            map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.activity_main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);   
            Log.d(tag, "json object  " + lv.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID " + o.get("id")+" " + o.get("name") + o.get("magnitude")+".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
 } 
}
```

**JSONFunctions.java**

```
package ayub.khosa.json_parsing;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
public class JSONfunctions {
public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";
JSONArray jArray = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    jArray = new JSONArray(result);            
return jArray;
}
}
```

Problem is that appears no data on screen and i get only a warning:

```
09-21 12:09:26.225: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
09-21 12:09:26.500: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43ee8ee8 ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity}
```

UPDATE :

Indeed the webserver was down without i noticed. Now is up, i see in browser the json, but now i get the following errors:

```
     09-21 12:30:52.301: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43f44da0 ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity}
     09-21 12:30:57.449: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity }
     09-21 12:30:57.609: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc ayub.khosa.json_parsing for activity ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity: pid=287 uid=10036 gids={3003}
     09-21 12:30:58.179: D/AYUB(287): setContentView  
     09-21 12:30:58.339: D/AYUB(287): json object  
     09-21 12:30:58.339: D/AndroidRuntime(287): Shutting down VM
     09-21 12:30:58.339: W/dalvikvm(287): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ayub.khosa.json_parsing/ayub.khosa.json_parsing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:193)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init(JSONArray.java:70)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at ayub.khosa.json_parsing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
     09-21 12:30:58.349: E/AndroidRuntime(287):     ... 11 more
     09-21 12:30:58.419: D/dalvikvm(287): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3711 objects / 261576 bytes in 67ms
     09-21 12:30:58.429: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity
     09-21 12:30:58.958: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{440757b8 ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity}
     09-21 12:31:02.689: I/Process(287): Sending signal. PID: 287 SIG: 9
     09-21 12:31:02.709: I/ActivityManager(59): Process ayub.khosa.json_parsing (pid 287) has died.
     09-21 12:31:02.729: W/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43e4ec30
     09-21 12:31:09.089: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{440757b8 ayub.khosa.json_parsing/.MainActivity}


UPDATE 2 - after Max edit suggestion

>  09-21 13:08:24.395: D/AYUB(272): setContentView 

>  09-21 13:08:24.475: I/global(272): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.

>  09-21 13:08:24.475: W/System.err(272): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 

>  09-21 13:08:24.485: W/System.err(272):   at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)

>  09-21 13:08:24.485: W/System.err(272):   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at ayub.khosa.json_parsing.JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(JSONfunctions.java:41)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at ayub.khosa.json_parsing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

>  09-21 13:08:24.495: W/System.err(272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: W/System.err(272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: W/System.err(272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: W/System.err(272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: W/System.err(272):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: D/AYUB(272): json object  

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: D/AndroidRuntime(272): Shutting down VM

>  09-21 13:08:24.505: W/dalvikvm(272): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ayub.khosa.json_parsing/ayub.khosa.json_parsing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:193)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:70)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at ayub.khosa.json_parsing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

>  09-21 13:08:24.515: E/AndroidRuntime(272):   ... 11 more

>  09-21 13:08:27.035: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 272 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you try to run `http://192.168.0.104/earthquakes.json` over browser? what do you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your GET a bit:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
  entity.consumeContent();
}

...

InputStream is = entity.getContent();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader sb = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;

while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();

    result=sb.toString();

   // before conversion to JSONArray print it:
   Log.d("Fess", result);

   jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

**[EDIT]**

from your logs I see:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:193)
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim for suggestion, but i get: InputStream is = entity.getContent(); - duplicate local variale is

Comment: @Alec  so type only `is = entity.getContent();`

Comment: `BufferedReader sb = new BufferedReader(isr);`

Comment: try{
        
   JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result);
//         // ...

         for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){                        
             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
             JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

by line JSONArray json = new JSONArray(result); - cause 2 eclipse error:  result cannot be resolved to a variable / duplicate local variable json

Comment: add `String result = ""`,  man I did my best and I can't observe each row. its basic

Comment: Still nothing... can you please check the entire code on your PC ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest changing the JSON format into :

`{"earthquake" : [Your Original JSON Here]}`

To parse the JSON, you will need to create a new `JSONObject`, for example, we save the json string into a string called `jsontext`, create a new `JSONObject` like :

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsontext);
```

take the array "earthquake" :

```
JSONArray Earthquake = mainObject.getJSONArray("earthquake");
```

then just parse it like usual.

For some reason, the JSONArray will be null if you create it without encapsulating it inside an object.

Hope this helps, Good luck ^^

Regards,

Reid

**EDIT :** 
Check whether this code has the JSON String -> `result=sb.toString();`

Append the string like this : `String jsondata = "{\"data\":" + result + "}";`

Parse the json as I explained above

Comment: Thank you reidzeibel, but i don`t have access to json source. earthquake.json is only a example i used and is comparable with my original json. Is somewhere online and i must use it "as is"

Comment: I see, then why don't you append the JSON String? :p for example :
`String appendedJson = "{\"objectname\" : " + yourarray + "}";`

Comment: Knowing they i am totally new in java and android programming, can you please be more specific ? In fact is a good ideea. A lot of people have exactly my problem as mine, but no one yet has come with a exact example / tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an opensource project in http://remotegun.com on Android and Xcode.
contact with this address [earthquake app](http://remotegun.com/earthquake-early-warning-system/)